# Conceptual Question about Memoryless Property an Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let's say I am given $X\sim \exp$ with mean=3, and then I am also asked to find $E[X-8|X>8]$. By memoryless property of the exponential distribution  $E[X-8|X>8]=E[X]=3$. However, I am trying trouble understanding how it is mathematically possible in such a situation for the expected value to be = 3 when 3 < 8 seeing as we have the condition that X > 8?

Comment: It is the expected value of $X-8$. The expected value of $X$ is larger by $8$, i.e. it is $11$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$Y = X - 8 \mid X > 8.$$  What does this mean?  Let's consider an example.  Say you are waiting at a train platform and $$X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\mu = 3)$$ represents the random amount of time (in minutes) it takes for the next train to arrive.  So on average, your waiting time is $3$ minutes.

Now, say you have been waiting and $8$ minutes have passed and the train has not yet arrived.  The random variable $Y$ represents the amount of **additional** time that you will wait for the next train to arrive.  The total time you wait is still $X$, and you know it has been more than $8$ minutes, but you won't know exactly what $X$ is until the train does arrive.

Because $X$ is exponentially distributed, and because of the memoryless property, it actually turns out that $Y$ is also exponentially distributed with mean $3$ minutes.  That is to say, given you have already waited more than $8$ minutes with no train, the average time to wait until the next train is still $3$ minutes!  This seems rather counterintuitive (and is one of criticisms of exponentially distributed event time models).  After all, if the average wait time was originally $3$ minutes and you already waited $8$ minutes, wouldn't it be more likely that a train will arrive soon?  Perhaps in a real-world scenario, yes.  But as we said earlier, this is just a hypothetical example to illustrate how the exponential distribution behaves.  Memorylessness is a property that, *given how much time you have already waited, the amount of additional time to wait does not depend on how much time has passed.*  A discrete analogy to this phenomenon that does make sense is coin flipping:  the outcome of a coin toss does not depend on the outcomes that were observed before.  The familiar ["gambler's fallacy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) is that if you toss a fair coin many times and see, say, $10$ heads in a row, you might be inclined to think that the next toss will be more likely to be heads than tails.  But if the coin is by definition fair, this is not true--the probability of heads remains $1/2$ even if the previous tosses were all heads.  That's why it's called "memoryless"--the coin does not **remember** what it did in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$, because expectation is linear. And in the case where $Y$ is a constant $y$, $E(Y) = E(y) = y$.

So $E(X - 8 | X > 8) = E(X | X > 8) + E(-8 | X > 8) = E(X | X > 8) - 8$.

Without knowing the distribution of $X$, the only thing you can say about $E(X | X > 8)$ (assuming it even exists) is that it is going to be at least 8. So we're going to find something that's at least 8, and subtract 8 from it, which means we're going to get a value that's greater than 0, but that's all we can know for sure.

Imagine flipping a coin 20 times, and calling $H$ the number of heads. What's $E(H - 15)$? We know that $0 \leq H \leq 20$ always holds, so $-15 \leq H - 15 \leq 5$ and hence $-5 \leq E(H - 15) \leq 5$. If our coin is fair, then $E(H - 15) = -5$, which is a negative number despite the number of heads being positive.